# react router server side rendering: How to get route params on server side?

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router

OK, I'm still trying to build react.js app with server side rendering. I having big time dealing with react-router with parameters. I cannot extract routes params from route on server side to make proper query on DB.

Here is my react-router route:

```
import {Router,Route} from "react-router";
import React from "react";
import App from "../components/app";
import {HomeContainer} from "../components/home";
import {TagContainer} from "../components/tag";

export function createRouter(hist) {
    const routes = <Route component={App}>
        <Route path="/" component={HomeContainer}/>
        <Route path="/tag/:unique_name" name="tag" component={TagContainer}/>
    </Route>;
    return (
        <Router history={hist}>{routes}</Router>
    );
}
```

the route run fine until I add parameter ":unique_name" to the route

```
<Route path="/tag/:unique_name" name="tag" component={TagContainer}/>
```

on the server side, I cannot extract unique_name from the route to make query on DB:

Here is the route on server(Using Node.js & Express.js):

```
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/tag/:unique_name", ServerRenderController.tagRender);
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '/build')));
server.use(router);
```

and here is my "ServerRenderController.tagRender":

```
    function tagRender(req, res) {
            console.log(req.params.unique_name);
/*
output :
mytag_unique_name -> this is the route params
style.css ->stylesheet - how the hell it become route params?
app.js -> client code - how the hell it become route params?
vendor.js -> vendor scripts - how the hell it become route params?
manifest.js -> manifest file -how the hell it become route params?
*/
     match({browserHistory,routes, location:req.url}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps)=> {
            if (redirectLocation) {
                //@TODO: response redirect location
                console.log('redirect location');
            }
            if (err) {
                //@TODO: response error
                console.log(err.stack);
            }
            if (!renderProps) {
                //@TODO: route to 404
                console.log("no renderProps");
            }

            renderPage(renderProps); // return HTML to client with __PRELOADED_STATE__
        }
```

**Questions :**

1. What did I do wrong in server code (routing, express static
   middleware...).
2. How do I extract correct route params from route? (I only want to extract "mytag_unique_name" as the only params when I browse to http://localhost/tag/mytag_unique_name)
       right now the route params including static files that should be
       send as MIMETYPE css/js.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Turn out I made mistake in references to style sheets and scripts file. 
In the server render code must refer `<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` 
with slash (/) at the begining of the `rel` attr. 
Note here for anyone have same problem.